# sqlite count returns one less record

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an Sqlite database and i work with it inside an android app. It has records with id's starting to 1 to 199. I run this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from mytable
```

I expect the result is 199 but it gives me 198!! Why? Why one less record?

Comment: Can you inspect the actual database and confirm there are 199 records?

Comment: Is *every* id used? Check that *all* numbers are used (no gaps) by inspecting the output of `select * from mytable order by id`

Comment: Side note.  If you inserted them with the 'insert' method on the SQLDatabase class, use 'insertOrThrow' instead.  No idea what your code looks like, but the 'insert' method just logs errors and keeps going.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT id+1 FROM mytable WHERE id+1 NOT IN (SELECT id FROM mytable) AND id<199`?

Answer (score 0):

It was my own mistake! While inserting record i lose on of them. And that cause the problem. sorry everybody